# Setting Ratchet ws connection from same server

Tags: php, websocket, vps, ratchet

Im Trying to make my ratchet server works online,

so I bought vps , and uploaded all site files to **htdocs** in **xampp**,

Firewall and port 8080 is adjusted, so problem isn't from here,

my server code

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new chat_server()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
```

js connection

```
var ws = new WebSocket("wss://example.com:8080/ws");
```

I adjusted modules in httpd.conf files

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

and in httpd-proxy.conf

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /ws https://example.com:8080
```

and for sure in **cmd** Im running the file

```
php server.php
```

but it still gives

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com:8080/ws' failed:

what Im missing, Its been a week nearly trying to make it work :DD

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you are redirecting in the wrong manner.

In the statement `ProxyPass /ws https://example.com:8080` you should redirect the `ws` subdomain to HTTP, not HTTPS. So write

`ProxyPass /ws/ http://example.com:8080/` or if the socket server  is local try `ProxyPass /ws/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/`